# Basic question: why and how smooth convex function $f(x)$ with domain $R^n$ is equivalent to $g(x):= \frac{L}{2} x^T x - f(x)$?

Tags: convex-analysis

I am so sorry to ask probably the most trivial and fundamental question. But it is just bothering me and not able to understand,

> why and how smooth convex function $f(x)$ with domain $R^n$ is equivalent to another convex function $g(x):= \frac{L}{2} x^T x - f(x)$?

(reference: page 1-11 of http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf)

I am so confused. If I minimize the function $f(x)$, then I need to maximize the function $g(x)$, right? or I have confused myself more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder you're confused, since you're reading it all wrong.

The claim that they make is that “**this**” (which refers to **the inequality at the top of the page**, not to the function $f$) is equivalent to **the condition that $\frac{L}{2} x^T x - f(x)$ is convex**, provided that $f$ is convex with domain $\mathbf{R}^n$.

(What would it even *mean* for a *function* $f$ to be equivalent to another *function* $g$ in this context?)

And it also says “we will see that”, meaning (I suppose) that you will get an explanation of why this is true later in the text, or in a later lecture perhaps (since this seems to be lecture notes). So just keep reading on and see if it gets clearer.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you so much for the clarification. I started to think it is some kind of convex conjugate :|.. As you said, I must continue and try to understand ...